# Import package from adjacent module works in Py2 but not in Py3

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, python-2.x, importerror

I'm still getting used to structuring python projects and relative imports, I thought I understood relative imports mostly until I ran into an issue when testing on Py3.

I have a project that is structure like so:

```
scriptA.py
package/__init__.py
          scriptB.py
          scriptC.py
```

and `__init.py__` contains the following:

```
from scriptB import functionB
from scriptC import functionC
```

In `scriptA` `import package as _package` works in Py2.7, but fails on Py3.5 with the error, `ImportError: No module named 'scriptB'`.

How can I import `package` in a way that is compatible with both Py2 and 3? Why is this different?

I tried doing `import .package as _package` but that doesn't seem to change anything (still figuring out when to use `.` and `..`...

Comment: I think you are doing an implicit relative import, which is disallowed in Py3.  If you type `from __future__ import absolute_import` this should turn off implicit rel. imports in Py2 as well and raise the same error as in Py3. "Using dots" as demonstrated by @pbreach is an example of an [explicit relative import](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) which is both Py2/3 compatible.  Use either explicit relative or absolute imports instead, never implicit.

Answer (score 0):

**No module named 'scriptB'**

Looks like a path error.  Check your path statement.
  The path statement in Windows can be accessed by typing "system" into start menu search bar.  From there you can access "Environment Variables", one of which is the "path" statement.  There you can see different directories that are allowed to be accessed by Python scripts.  Make sure your Python 3.x directory and Python 3.x/scripts directory are listed there.
  Files listed in the path statement are kind of like Global Variables in a program.  If both Python 2 and Python 3 have the **same** file names in their directories you could access an incompatible file.  I've read that there is a python launcher which will solve this very problem so that you can run multiple versions of python on the same computer.
  For now I would test to see if this is your problem by 
-copying the path statement to a backup file and then 
-remove references to python 2.x, 
-reboot
-run your program.
If you want to run multiple versions of python copy the original path statement back and install the python launcher.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Could you be more clear? Do you mean check sys.path, and if so what I am checking for. This is a comment not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that the imports in `__init__.py` should have been relative imports i.e.:

```
from .scriptB import functionB
from .scriptC import functionC
```

I guess this is one of the differences between importing a module and a python package. It seems that in Py3.5 relative imports need to be done explicitly and so an error was thrown. This is my interpretation. unfortunatly the structure I had put in the question was not close enough to the problem I had, so this doesn't solve it... But a more detailed (and probably accurate) answer for this is still welcomed.